# How can I put a bullet in a iso-8859-15 HTML document in a pre tag?

Tags: html, character-encoding

I want to put a bullet in a pre tag, without using any special html characters.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-15" />
</head>
<body>
<pre>
   bullet here!
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried pasting various bullets in but they all show up as question marks or foreign characters.

Comment: What do you mean by "without using any special html characters"? What is a "special HTML character"? And why don't you want to use it?

Comment: I mean things like &bullet; or like &#8729;. I don't want to use them because the HTML is inside an XML feed.

Comment: Then, is your question related to your problem?

Comment: Why do you expect that `&#8729;` would not work in XML feed? If it does not, the processing of the feed is broken. (But note that `&#8729;` is BULLET OPERATOR “∙”, which is different from `&#x2022;` BULLET “•”. Make sure you know which character you want.)

Comment: The reason why is I am calling HttpUtility.HtmlDecode to strip out the special html characters because that is our client's requirement not to have named characters like bullet.  It is also taking our the numeric ones. I think what I really want is something to take out the named ones and leave the numeric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<pre>` tag does not affect the way HTML behaves beyond white space collapsing. Everything that works in a `<div>` should work in `<pre>`. For instance:

```
&bullet; // Prints •
```

You're probably typing raw UTF-8 characters, thus the misprints (your doc uses ISO-8859-15, not UTF-8).

If client doesn't want neither UTF-8 nor HTML entities he simply cannot have bullets: ISO-8859-15 has around 191 printable characters that include `*`, `º` or `·` but not anything that's technically a bullet. If you want to type raw characters you must choose one that belongs to [ISO-8859-15](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15).

IMHO, the requirement is kind of weird. XML and HTML are different things. It's possible that you're simply not escaping text properly when you generate your XML. All decent XML libraries take care of that automatically but if you're using simple string contacatenation you should be doing it yourself. E.g.:

```
<this-is-xml>
<![CDATA[
    <p>This is no longer XML</p>
]]>
</this-is-xml>
```